# Image processing library to make a curl image from a flat image in iOS or C#

Tags: ios, image, image-processing

I want to create a iOS app and a CMS (using C#) to manage image data. The image processing can be implemented at client side or server side.

The question: Is there any image processing library to make a **curl image** from a **flat image** in **iOS** or **C#**?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Input a flat image:
[image]

Output will be a curl image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library to achieve that. Specifically you can use GPUImageTransformFilter(affineTransform/transform3D) to transform the flat image. It's not possible to do the shadow and magazine pages, but you can have a template image which you can super-impose with a transformed flat image to do this.

If its too much for an iPhone, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) on the server-side to do that for you.

Hope this helps.